# First time working with exceptions. I'm having difficulty understanding exceptions

Tags: c++

This is my first time working with exceptions and I'm having some issues understanding them. This is my C++ assignment. I need help from you guys. I always get solution(s) to my problem(s) when I ask you guys here on this site. Thanks!

**Here is the output I'm getting when I run my Program:**

```
An exception test is about to take place.
```

AnnounceDestroyed is created.
AnnounceDestroyed is destroyed.
-1

An exception test is about to take place.
AnnounceDestroyed is created.
AnnounceDestroyed is destroyed.
Error!

An exception test is about to take place.
AnnounceDestroyed is created.
An exception was attempted, but did not occur.
AnnounceDestroyed is destroyed.
An exception did not take place.

I used throw in two my virtual functions and they seem to work fine but when I try to use it in the third function compiler gives me an error.
If you scroll down you will find my comment where compiler giving me an error.
Here is my Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    using namespace std;


    class AnnounceDestroyed
    {
        public:
        AnnounceDestroyed(){std::cout << "AnnounceDestroyed is created."   << std::endl;}
       ~AnnounceDestroyed(){std::cout << "AnnounceDestroyed is destroyed." << std::endl;}
    };

    class ExceptionThrower
    {
        public:
            virtual void launchException() = 0;
            virtual ~ExceptionThrower(){};
    };

    class IntThrower : public ExceptionThrower
    {
        private:
            int thrwVar;
        public:
            IntThrower(int var){thrwVar = var;}
            void launchException()
        {
            throw thrwVar;
        }
    };

    class MsgThrower : public ExceptionThrower
    {
        private:
            string msgStr;
        public:
            MsgThrower(string str){msgStr = str;}
        void launchException()
        {
            throw msgStr;
        }

    };

    class CustomThrower : public ExceptionThrower
    {
        private:
            int customInt;
            string customStr;
        public:
            CustomThrower(int cstmInt, string cstmString)
                         {customInt = cstmInt; customStr = cstmString;}
            void launchException()
        {
            //throw customStr; // when I user throw here compiler gives me an error for some reasons.
// here is the error : "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"
            //throw customInt;   // And here as well.
        }
    };

    class CustomException
    {
        private:
            int cstmExpInt;
            string cstmExpStr;
        public:
            CustomException(int aInt, string bStr)
                          {cstmExpInt = aInt; cstmExpStr = bStr;}
        void printContents()
        {

            std::cout << cstmExpStr << std::endl;
            std::cout << cstmExpInt << std::endl;
        }
    };


    void activateException(ExceptionThrower &currentThrower)
    {
        shared_ptr<AnnounceDestroyed> announce = make_shared<AnnounceDestroyed>();
        currentThrower.launchException();
        std::cout << "An exception was attempted, but did not occur." << std::endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        // Constants
        const int INT_THROWER_CODE = -1;
        const string MSG_THROWER_STRING = "Error!";
        const int CUSTOM_THROWER_CODE = -99;
        const string CUSTOM_THROWER_STRING = "Major error!";

        int exceptionCounter = 0;

        IntThrower LauncherInt(INT_THROWER_CODE);
        MsgThrower LauncherMsg(MSG_THROWER_STRING);
        CustomThrower LauncherCustom(CUSTOM_THROWER_CODE, CUSTOM_THROWER_STRING);

        try {
            std::cout << "An exception test is about to take place." << std::endl;
            activateException(LauncherInt);
            std::cout << "An exception did not take place." << std::endl;

        }
        catch (int &a)
        {
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;


        }
        try {
            std::cout << "An exception test is about to take place." << std::endl;
            activateException(LauncherMsg);
            std::cout << "An exception did not take place." << std::endl;

        }
        catch (string &b)
        {
            std::cout << b << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;

        }
        try {
            std::cout << "An exception test is about to take place." << std::endl;
            activateException(LauncherCustom);
            std::cout << "An exception did not take place." << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        catch (CustomException &c)
        {
            c.printContents();

        }    
    }
```

Comment: As a general advice: You should only use exceptions derived from `std::exception` instead of primitives.

Comment: It's extremely difficult for us to help you unless you first make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There are no `throw` in your code ...

Comment: @SaadArshad That would make a good question, no?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean `throw` _is_ the way to **throw** exceptions. If you're having a problem using `throw`, then you can ask a question about that. It should include the text of the error you're getting and a [mcve]. But you haven't included any of this information or code in your question.

Comment: ok. I'll do that.

Comment: Your program fails because you failed to catch the exception that was thrown. `LauncherCustom` throws `string`, so you need to catch that. You should read this [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 'throw' clause to throw an exception.

Maybe you'll get what you want if you change 'launchException' to:

```
void launchException() override
    {
         std::cout << customInt << std::endl;
         std::cout << customStr << std::endl;
         throw CustomException(customInt, customStr);
    }
```

Also note the 'override' keyword. It may help avoiding the warnings you mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help but compiler says "Invalid use of incomplete type 'CustomException'

Comment: BTW, it seems to be more preferable to add noreturn attribute as `[[noreturn]] void launchException()` to avoid unnecessary false-positive warnings.

Comment: @SaadArshad try to move the declaration of CustomException uppwards on your source -- before it is used.

Comment: I moved CustomException class upward and it worked. But it doesn't work with forward declarations.

Comment: In c++ there is the concept of definition and declaration. You need the definition (what usually goes into the .h or .hpp file) to go before use. The declaration may happen after usage. Maybe I have swapped the terms ... ;)

Comment: Terminology backward, @zertyz . Declaration says that an identifier exists and will be defined elsewhere. It must be before first use. Definition can go anywhere before a usage requires a the definition (which may turn out to be anywhere). I screw this up all the time, too.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! You guys are awesome!